# Ambiguous mention of NAVAIDs with duplicate names in FAA's CIFP file (ARINC-424 18 format)

Tags: instrument-procedures, navaids, arinc-424

I am studying *FAA*'s Coded Instrument Flight Procedures (*CIFP*) dataset ([link](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/cifp/download/)), coded in ARINC-424 18 format, and I noticed that navaids are coded for the purposes of an *IFP* simulation only by their short name. The problem is, a number of navaids have duplicate names.

Take, for example, this sample from *CIFP*, describing [*ELMAA3*](https://aeronav.faa.gov/d-tpp/1901/00582elmaa.pdf#nameddest=(SEA)) departure procedure:

[image]

It's impossible to distinguish if the VI leg during this departure procedure has to intercept a course beginning from either *SEA VORTAC* or *SEA VOT*. Both are near the airport but significantly far from each other.

Am I missing something? Perhaps only certain types of navaids are used? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: A VOT is not a navaid.  It's a test signal generator for VOR receivers. The procedure intercepts the radial to the VORTAC.